# Javascript: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined // but when I try it in console, it works

Tags: javascript, console

I get the error `Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined` by executing a script but when I try it in console it works fine.

Here's my function:

```
function checkEmpty(){
  td = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].classList.contains('atharva_minicart_empty')
  if (td){
    minicart = document.getElementById('atharva_minicart')
    minicart.classList.add('minicart_empty')
  }
}
```

And console gives me error on this line

```
td = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].classList.contains('atharva_minicart_empty')
```

But when I try it in console it works. What's the problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you calling the function when the element `td` already exists?

Comment: Where did you place the `console.log`? Maybe the function is called before `td` is rendered.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) -> Please make this an actual [mcve]

Comment: @FabrizioCalderanlovestrees thanks I needed to setTimeout in order to load the elements first, silly me

Comment: Either add it as an answer and accept it, or delete that question. Imho deleting it would be the better option as `setTimeout` isn't really an "answer" because this just breaks to easily.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are querying for an id, while your element seems to have a class? Maybe this is the error?

The error means that minicart is undefined. The line in which you're trying to define minicart seems to be the problem.

Comment: An assumption is not really an answer. This should be a comment.

Comment: I added an explanation.

Comment: This is still just a comment. And without an actual [mcve] from OP we all can just guess what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace that line:

`td = document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0].classList.contains('atharva_minicart_empty')`

with the better one:

`td = document.querySelector('.atharva_minicart_empty')`

When your page doesn't have any `td` or a random `td` appear before `atharva_minicart_empty`, then `document.getElementsByTagName('td')[0]` will throw error.